# Setting PHP timeout for xml fopen

Tags: php, apache, fopen

While accessing xml file with `fopen` that don’t exist we get

> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!

But it takes 30 seconds. How to return this error immediately or short after not finding a file.

Also, why when file is not found Apache scans lots of ports?

Comment: Check with file_exists function and then use fopen...

Comment: Doing exacly that; Error occurs when calling xml file over http

Comment: Do you get an HTTP response code?

Comment: HTTP response code ike what?

Comment: With your PHP error do you get a HTTP response code like: `"HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found"`? You say that the XML file you are trying to `fopen` does not exist, so there should be a 404, otherwise there may be a different kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the way, You have to use fopen itself to check whether it exists or not,

```
function fileExists($path){
     return (@fopen($path,"r")==true);
}

if(fileExists('http://example.com/test/file.xml'))
{ 
    echo "exists";
}
else
{
    echo "not_exist";
}
```